Powers of 5 in an infinite product series
Consider the highest power of 5 in the product $1^1. 2^2 . 3^3 .....n^n$ is given by $H(n)$ (i.e., $H(n)$ denotes the largest integer $k$ such that $5^k$ is an integral dvisior of the above product. Then the value of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {n^2}{H(n)}$.
My try:

I tried writing the product series till small terms and looking for a general pattern, but obviously that turned out a wrong approach.
This one was a little more promising.
I realised that at every multiple of 5, there was a power of 5 added, for ex. $5^5$ . $10^5$, but the problem with this method was, at every number which was of the form $5^n$, there were multiple powers of 5 added in every subsequent term of series, ex. $25^{25} = 5^{2*25}$ which is also repeated in its other multiples, ex. 50,75, etc.

I have no further ideas on how to proceed and will appreciate any help.
EDIT-1: For some reason, my post for genuine help needed is being downvoted, I would really like it if someone could tell me the reason people are not liking it because I can not see any problems.
EDIT-2: I just wanted to take a moment to thank all those people who decided to help me instead of silent downvoting, thank you.
For Brian Tung's answer:
In my similar attempt I get a identical series, but summing it the "normal" way yields a different result and I am not very clear on how you summed it.
Here's how I summed it
$H(n) = (5+10+15+...) + (25+50+75+......) + (125+250+......)+......$
taking 5, 25, 125, 625, $5^5$,...$5^n$ etc nth power of 5 from respective terms in series.
$H(n) = 5(1+2+3+....) + 25(1+2+3+....) + 125(1+2+3+.....)$
sum of each series in bracket equals to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
hence, $H(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} [5 + 25 + 125 + 625 +....+ 5^n$]
now the last series, is a Geometric progression of powers of 5, hence by summing it using the summation rules for Geometric Progression $\frac{a_1(r^n-1)}{r-1}$ (we can not use infinite summation because, r=5(>1), hence we get the final solution as:
$$ H(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{5(5^n-1)}{4}$$
but I have been able to guess this must be wrong since it gives the limit as 0 and also with smaller values of 'n' we can simply check and it doesn't returns the expected answer.
I have been able to guess why is my formula wrong, for because it assumes the higher power of 5 (25, 125) start off with the first term, so for n =1, it adds all powers of 5, so far I have been unable to understand how to correct the mistake I am making
Using $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ instead of $\frac{n^2}{2}$ (in Brian Tung's answer)
$$ H(n) = 5\frac{(\frac{n}{5})(\frac{n}{5}+1)}{2} + 25\frac{(\frac{n}{25})(\frac{n}{25}+1)}{2} + 125\frac{(\frac{n}{125})(\frac{n}{125}+1)}{2}+....$$
$$ H(n) = \frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{n+5}{5} + \frac{n+25}{25} + \frac{n+125}{125} +.....\right)$$
$$ H(n) = \frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{n}{5} + 1 +\frac{n}{25} + 1 + \frac{n}{125} + 1.....\right)$$
$$ H(n) = \frac{n}{2}\left((n)(\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{25}+ \frac{1}{125}+ ....) (1+1+1+...n times)\right)$$
$$ H(n) = \frac{n}{2}\left((n)(\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{1-\frac{1}{5}}) + n\right)$$  (used summation of GP with common ratio 1/5)
$$H(n) = \frac{n^2}{2}\left((1)(\frac{1}{4})+1\right)$$
$$H(n) = \frac{5n^2}{8}$$
Mistake: in the above derivation
(credits to Brian Tung for spotting it)
I do not have n 1's, I have $\log_5 n$ 1's which will be much smaller than n or $n^2$ hence can be neglected.

You can find the solution by searching better.
(1) Is there something special about 5? Would it work the same for 2? 3? 4?
(2) Write out your effort in more detail. What new variables did you define, what did you obtain, etc ?

Reminiscent of Legendre’s formula but different

Unfortunately, over the last few years, there is an increased culture of silent down-voting and close-voting. I don't agree with it except in situations where the OP is clearly disrespecting the community, and this is not one of those cases. Nothing to do about it except to do whatever you can to improve the post, I'm afraid.

@BrianTung I see, thank you for the suggestions, I will keep them in mind for my next posts

@Kolja, I have updated my answer to reflect on my attempts.

You're fine up until (and including) $H(n) = 5(1+2+3+\cdots) + 25(1+2+3+\cdots) + 125(1+2+3+\cdots)+\cdots$. After that, it goes wrong, because you haven't carefully figured out how many terms there are in each parenthetical expression. Certainly there are not $n$ terms in each one, so your next line is not right. I would recommend trying it with $n = 5^5 = 3125$, and figure out explicitly how many terms there are in each parenthetical expression.

@BrianTung so can I say, in the first term of the series, if there are n terms, 5(1+2+3+...) then there will be n/5 in 25(1+2+3+...) and n/25 in 125(1+2+3+....) and subsequent pattern?

Hey @wannabemathematician it's complete. You can check out my answer

hey @Gwen I loved the answer, but unfortuanately it is a bit too verbose for my level, but I appreciate the effort regardless, it gave me a totally new way to look at the problem, I appreciate that, thank you. It was a very interesting approach

This question has two upvoted answers.  What "details or clarity" does it need?

Anyone who reads my comments, can someone please let me know where did I go wrong? what's missing in my question? for it to be closed, what details and clarity is it missing?

Sketch of derivation. In the product
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n k^k
$$
we observe that

The $5j$th term adds $5j$ powers of $5$, except that
The $25j$th term adds an additional $25j$ powers of $5$, except that
The $125j$th term adds an additional $125j$ powers of $5$, except that
And so on.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
H(n) & = (5 + 10 + 15 + \cdots + \text{about $n$}) \\
     & + (25 + 50 + 75 + \cdots + \text{about $n$}) \\
     & + (125 + 250 + 375 + \cdots + \text{about $n$}) \\
     & + \cdots
\end{align}
where the "about $n$" in each row is the largest multiple of $5, 25, 125, \ldots$ not exceeding $n$. Approximate the triangular sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k$ by $n^2/2$; this is asymptotically accurate for large $n$. Then
\begin{align}
H(n) & \approx 5\frac{(n/5)^2}{2}
             + 25\frac{(n/25)^2}{2}
             + 125\frac{(n/125)^2}{2}
             + \cdots \\
     & = \frac{n^2}{2\cdot5} + \frac{n^2}{2\cdot25}
       + \frac{n^2}{2\cdot125} + \cdots \\
     & = \frac{n^2}{2\cdot5\left(1-\frac15\right)} \\
     & = \frac{n^2}{8}
\end{align}
Therefore, the desired limit is $8$. Some numerical tests show this to be the right value, if I've coded things correctly. The above is not quite rigorous, but should be enough of a scaffold to build a rigorous solution on.

A similar line of reasoning shows that the corresponding limit for base $b$ (where $b = 5$ here) is $2b-2$.

I have been able to understand that, the way you did the summation (n/5)^2/2 etc. is that so it works out for smaller values of n (values such as n = 1 2 3 4) because there is no power of 5 for it, but I am not sure how you came up with that, I have updated my question asking for a clearance, please take a look at it, thank you.

If we were not to approximate $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ as $\frac{(n^2)}{2}$, we will get the sum as $\frac{5n^2}{8}$, which is vastly different from the $\frac{n^2}{8}$ which get get from approximation, how will that be accounted for?

@wannabemathematician: I can't answer that question, since I don't follow that conclusion. How would an input error that is on the order of one part in $n^2$ produce an output error of a factor of five? I think you'll have to show how you obtain that conclusion. ¶ Also, numerical experiments validate $n^2/8$, so I expect there's some small wrinkle in your derivation.

I have updated my answer to include the derivation of my attempt, please take a look at it see if I commited an error, thank you

also I would like to know how did you validate $n^2$/8, I am interested in the numerical experiments for future references

Your error is in the expression $(1+1+1+\cdots+\text{$n$ times})$. You don't have $n$ $1$'s. You have on the order of $\log_5 n$ $1$'s. ¶ As far as the numerical experiments go, I brute forced it. I literally looped from $1$ through $n$ and counted up factors of $5$. There are more efficient ways of doing it, but brute force was fast enough. For $n = 1,000,000$, it took a second or so to get a ratio of $7.999+$.

Oh right, I found the mistake, thank you for spotting it for me, I really appreciate the help, and I also appreciate the efforts you put in to brute force it, thank you.

I think in general, you have to be a bit more careful about generalizing. Did you actually run through a precise evaluation for $n = 3125$? If you had, you would have seen that you didn't have $3125$ $1$'s.

I'm glad you figured it out.

nope I did not generalize it for n=3125, I only did it for smaller values and hence couldn't find the mistake. I appreciate the help. thanks!

We see that the pattern is like this,
$$1^1×...5^5×...(10)^{10}×...(15)^{15}×...(25)^{25}×...×(125)^{125}...(5x)^{5x}×...n^n$$
By laws of indices, we can write these as$$1^1×...5^5×...(5^{10}×2^{10})×...(5^{15}×3^{15})×...×5^{50}×...(5^{5x}×x^{5x})×...n^n$$
Thus$$5^k=(5^5×5^{10}×5^{15}×...5^{5[\frac{n}{5}]})×(5^{25}×5^{50}×5^{75}×...5^{25[\frac{n}{25}]})×(5^{125}×5^{250}×...×5^{125[\frac{n}{125}]})\\...\\(5^{(5^i)}×5^{(2.5^i)}×...×5^{5^i[\frac{n}{5^i}]})$$
Provided that $[\frac{n}{5^i}]≥1,i\in \mathbb{N}$
By properties of indices,
$$k=(5+10+15+...5[\frac{n}{5}])+(25+50+75+...25[\frac{n}{25}])+......(5^i+2.5^i+...5^i[\frac{n}{5^i}])\\=5(1+2+3+...[\frac{n}{5}])+25(1+2+3+...[\frac{n}{25}])+...+5^i(1+2+3+...[\frac{n}{5^i}])$$
Thus $$k=\frac{5[\frac{n}{5}]([\frac{n}{5}]+1)}{2}+\frac{25[\frac{n}{25}]([\frac{n}{25}]+1)}{2}+...\frac{5^i[\frac{n}{5^i}]([\frac{n}{5^i}]+1)}{2}$$
Basically $$k=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=1}^{i} {5^t[\frac{n}{5^t}]([\frac{n}{5^t}]+1)}$$
Where $i=\big[\log_5 n\big]$
Now we study the properties of $[.]$ function. For all $n>5$,
$$\frac{n}{5^i}-1<\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]≤\frac{n}{5^t}$$
$$\frac{n}{5^t}<\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]+1≤\frac{n}{5^t}+1$$
We multiply the two inequations to get
$$\frac{n}{5^t}\big(\frac{n}{5^t}-1\big)<\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]\bigg(\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]+1\bigg)≤\frac{n}{5^t}\big(\frac{n}{5^t}+1\big)$$
$$\implies \sum_{t=1}^i\frac{n}{5^t}\big(\frac{n}{5^t}-1\big)<\sum_{t=1}^i\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]\bigg(\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]+1\bigg)≤\sum_{t=1}^i\frac{n}{5^t}\big(\frac{n}{5^t}+1\big)$$
Applying reciprocal law and multiplying everyone by $\frac{2}{5^i}n^2$,
$$\frac{2n^2}{\sum_{t=1}^i{n}\big(\frac{n}{5^t}-1\big)}>\frac{2n^2}{\sum_{t=1}^i5^t\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]\bigg(\bigg[\frac{n}{5^t}\bigg]+1\bigg)}≥\frac{2n^2}{\sum_{t=1}^in\big(\frac{n}{5^t}+1\big)}$$
This turns into the form of $f(n)>g(n)≥h(n)$.
$$\lim_{n→\infty} f(n)=\lim_{n→∞} \frac{2n^2}{\sum_{t=1}^{[\log_5n]}\frac{n^2}{5^t}-n}=\lim_{n→∞} \frac{2}{\sum_{t=1}^{[\log_5n]}\frac{1}{5^t}-\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{2}{\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{1-\frac{1}{5}}}=8$$
$$\lim_{n→\infty} h(n)=\lim_{n→∞} \frac{2n^2}{\sum_{t=1}^{[\log_5n]}\frac{n^2}{5^t}+n}=\lim_{n→∞} \frac{2}{\sum_{t=1}^{[\log_5n]}\frac{1}{5^t}+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{2}{\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{1-\frac{1}{5}}}=8$$
I have used inf GP summation formula in the above limits
Thus by squeeze theorem, $$\lim_{n→∞} g(n)=\lim_{n→∞} \frac{n^2}{H(n)}=8$$

I am going through this, but it is not yet clear to me that you have considered that e.g., the largest power of $5$ that divides say $125^{125}$, isn't $5^{125}$ but is instead $5^{3 \times 125}$.

@Mike     I...did consider that didn't I? For $n=125, k=5^{125×13} $, not $3$ actually

Can you go into more detail on how you got that largest power of $5$ that divides $1^12^2 \cdots (125)^{125}$ is $5^{125 \times 13}$? [I gave the largest power that divides $125^{125}$.]

Oh wait @Mike now I understand your question. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit that in my answer. Thanks again

@Mike is this okay now? Can you help me a bit with the limit? It's appearing to be infinity

If you are not sure then you need to delete this until you are certain yourself, otherwise it is not really an answer.

@Mike I'm sure about my answer now. For n=125,i=3. Thus k=2125 according to my present formula. Which is true as $1.2^2.3^3....(125)^{125}$ has $(5^5×5^{10}×...5^{125}) × (5^{25}×5^{50}×...5^{125})×(5^{125})$. So $k=5(1+2+3+...25)+25(1+2+3+4+5)+125=2125$

@underflow has the right idea to finish off your expression with their fancy big-$\cal O$ notation. :-) ¶ Incidentally, you can use the left and right commands to obtain better-looking expressions; for example, $\left(\left[\frac{n}{5^t}\right]+1\right)$ yields $\left(\left[\frac{n}{5^t}\right]+1\right)$. It's a hassle, but it does look nicer.

I appreciate the answer and its very clear explanation, but I am not sure how will I use the summation you have obtained as your result in the limit, is there a way to approximate it?

@BrianTung Uhm....I don't know what's that. I have high school level knowledge...so I need some time to learn it and answer.
